# Django AbstractUser error when login in

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

I have created an AbstractUser model to add some extra fields to the standard usermodel.

I think everything is set up correctly, but when I log in, I get this error:

```
unbound method save() must be called with UserProfile instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Here is my accounts/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager, AbstractUser


class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    homephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)    

    objects = UserManager()
```

In my settings I have:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.UserProfile'
```

My Authentication Middleware:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import UserProfile


#Authentication Middleware using a external cookie named AUTHENTICATION
class CookieMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        #if not hasattr(request, 'userprofile'):
        #   raise ImproperlyConfigured()
        if "AUTHENTICATION" not in request.COOKIES:
            #Cookie not found - do nothing
            return

        #Token found - first check if the user is allready is logged in
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return

        #Not logged in, then send to RemoteUserBackend.py    
        token = request.COOKIES["AUTHENTICATION"]

        #Return if the cookie length is 0
        if len(token) == 0:
            return

        UserProfile = authenticate(token=token)
        request.UserProfile = UserProfile

        if request.UserProfile:
            login(request, request.UserProfile)
```

My RemoteUserBackend.py for login in external users:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from base64 import b64decode
from hashlib import sha1
from urllib import unquote
from sitetasks import tasks
from accounts.models import UserProfile


class Backend( object ):
        def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, token=None):

            #Unescape token
            unescaped_token = unquote(token)

            #Decode token
            decoded_token = unescaped_token.decode('base64')

            #Split the token into tree variable
            secret, hashstring, userID = decoded_token.split('-', 2)

            #Secret needs to bee in lower to match shared secret
            secret_lower = secret.lower()

            #Make string of SHARED_SECRET, hashstring, userID
            check_string = "%s%s%s" % (settings.SHARED_SECRET, hashstring, userID)

            #sha1 the string
            sha1_check_string = sha1(check_string)

            #Check if the SHARED_SECRET is matching cookie secret
            cookie_valid = sha1_check_string.hexdigest() == secret_lower

            if cookie_valid:
                try:
                    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(username=userID)

                    #The user exist, then update the user

                    #Make celery worker update user asynchronous
                    tasks.user_update.delay(user_id=userID)

                except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
                    # Create a new user

                    userprofile = UserProfile(username=userID)
                    userprofile.is_staff = False
                    userprofile.is_superuser = False



                    userprofile.save() #Save the user

                    #Make celery worker update user asynchronous
                    tasks.user_update.delay(user_id=userID)


                return UserProfile
            return None

        def get_user(self, user_id):
            try:
                return UserProfile.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
                return None
```

The traceback for the error I get is this:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://mydomain.com/

Django Version: 1.6.dev20130302084542
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'south',
 'djcelery',
 'gunicorn',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'template_utils',
 'compressor',
 'tagging',
 'ckeditor',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'mptt',
 'accounts',
)
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'myproj.CookieMiddleware.CookieMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/SITE/downloads/django-trunk/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  82.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/SITE/myproj/myproj/CookieMiddleware.py" in process_request
  35.             login(request, request.UserProfile)
File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/SITE/downloads/django-trunk/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  86.     user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/SITE/downloads/django-trunk/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  182.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/SITE/downloads/django-trunk/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in update_last_login
  31.     user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: unbound method save() must be called with UserProfile instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Anyone see what Im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend `authenticate()` method returns `UserProfile` (the class) instead of `userprofile` (the instance of that class belonging to the user).

Although there's nothing actually wrong in the middleware, it would be clearer if you kept to the same naming convention - which is the normal Python one - and referred to `request.userprofile` instead of `request.UserProfile`.